# How I'll fix it - NameError at /account/signup/ name 'SignUpForm' is not defined

Tags: python, django, frameworks, sign, account

I defined SignUpFrom but still, the server shows that name 'SignUpForm' is not defined by anyone, please suggest to me how I'll fix it. Thanks in advance.

Code Location: App_Login Views.py

```
views.py--App_Loginstrong text
[from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate, logout
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.


def sign_up(request):
    form = SignUpForm()
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            registered = True

    dict = {'form':form, 'registered':registered}
    return render(request, 'App_Login/signup.html', context=dict)

def login_page(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render(request, 'App_Login/login.html', context={'form':form})

@login_required
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import the sign up form too